# Deserialize hal+json to complex model

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following [HAL+JSON](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) sample:

```
{
    "id": "4a17d6fe-a617-4cf8-a850-0fb6bc8576fd",
    "country": "DE",
    "_embedded": {
      "company": {
        "name": "Apple",
        "industrySector": "IT",
      "owner": "Klaus Kleber",
      "_embedded": {
        "emailAddresses": [
          {
            "id": "4a17d6fe-a617-4cf8-a850-0fb6bc8576fd",
            "value": "test2@consoto.com",
            "type": "Business",
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "phoneNumbers": [
          {
            "id": "4a17d6fe-a617-4cf8-a850-0fb6bc8576fd",
            "value": "01670000000",
            "type": "Business",
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
        },
        "phoneNumbers": {
          "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
        },
        "addresses": {
          "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
        },
      }
    },
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
    },
    "legalPerson": {
      "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
    },
    "naturalPerson": {
      "href": "https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234"
    }
  }
}
```

And the following models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public LegalPerson Company { get; set; }
}
public class LegalPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IndustrySector { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
public class ContactInfo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, because of the `_embbeded`, I can't do an out-of-the-box serialization with `Newtonsoft.Json`, because then `Company` will be `null`;

I was hoping to see a [native hal+json support](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/297) by Json.NET, but it only has one recommendation to use a custom `JsonConverter`.

I started to create a custom one by myself, but feels like "reinventing the wheel" for me.

So, anyone knows a smart way to get out with this?

**UPDATE:**

- It's important to not change the models/classes. I can add attributes, but never change it's structures.

Comment: Did you take a look into hal serialize: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hal-serializer ?

Comment: @AhmedBinGamal I will do, but that's a node solution, I'm looking for a c# permanent one.

Comment: You said you can't change your models, how about extending or overriding them?

Comment: It's going to be a problem. The scenario I have here is, full working and on a production system, and the source of data schema was changed to hal+json response. I can't go and change the struct of, or extend/override, a model - otherwise, I will need to touch that whole system. I need a pinpoint approach. Add some attributes - which I can do at runtime - or add `JsonConverter`, or other options that I did not figure out.

Comment: maybe just use manual LINQ to JSON -> objects version without any deserialization? It might be easier than writing deserializer

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek that's nicer than create multiple `EmbeddedN` types, for sure. But image an already existing system. I can't change the type of each model to `dynamic`. That will bring chaos, no doubt. :)

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi you create your `Customer` instance in LINQ, no problem. Just instead of creating N classes and use annotations to move data from JSON to your classes you can just use LINQ to fill the properties

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek may you reply this question with a sample. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely solution is as suggested that you create a custom converter to parse the desired models.

In this case the custom converter would need to be able to read nested paths.

This should provide a simple workaround.

```
public class NestedJsonPathConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        var properties = jo.Properties();
        object targetObj = existingValue ?? Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        var resolver = serializer.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver;

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in objectType.GetProperties()
                                                .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)) {

            var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).ToArray();

            if (attributes.OfType<JsonIgnoreAttribute>().Any())
                continue;

            var jsonProperty = attributes.OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            var jsonPath = (jsonProperty != null ? jsonProperty.PropertyName : propertyInfo.Name);

            if (resolver != null) {
                jsonPath = resolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(jsonPath);
            }

            JToken token = jo.SelectToken(jsonPath) ?? GetTokenCaseInsensitive(properties, jsonPath);

            if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null) {
                object value = token.ToObject(propertyInfo.PropertyType, serializer);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(targetObj, value, null);
            }
        }
        return targetObj;
    }

    JToken GetTokenCaseInsensitive(IEnumerable<JProperty> properties, string jsonPath) {
        var parts = jsonPath.Split('.');

        var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p =>
            string.Equals(p.Name, parts[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        );

        for (var i = 1; i < parts.Length && property != null && property.Value is JObject; i++) {
            var jo = property.Value as JObject;
            property = jo.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p =>
                string.Equals(p.Name, parts[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            );
        }

        if (property != null && property.Type != JTokenType.Null) {
            return property.Value;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
         //Check if any JsonPropertyAttribute has a nested property name {name}.{sub}
        return objectType
            .GetProperties()
            .Any(p =>
                p.CanRead
                && p.CanWrite
                && p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                    .OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                    .Any(jp => (jp.PropertyName ?? p.Name).Contains('.'))
            );
    }

    public override bool CanWrite {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The original class structure now does not need to change, with only the properties that require custom paths needing to be decorated with `JsonPropertyAttribute` that indicates the path to populate the property.

In this example

```
public class Customer {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_embedded.company")]
    public LegalPerson Company { get; set; }
}
public class LegalPerson {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IndustrySector { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_embedded.emailAddresses")]
    public ContactInfo[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_embedded.phoneNumbers")]
    public ContactInfo[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Just include the converter as needed.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
};
settings.Converters.Add(new NestedJsonPathConverter());

var customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json, settings);
```

The two important parts of the code are the `GetTokenCaseInsensitive` method that searches for the requested token and allows for nested paths that can be case-insensitive.

```
JToken GetTokenCaseInsensitive(IEnumerable<JProperty> properties, string jsonPath) {
    var parts = jsonPath.Split('.');

    var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p =>
        string.Equals(p.Name, parts[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    );

    for (var i = 1; i < parts.Length && property != null && property.Value is JObject; i++) {
        var jo = property.Value as JObject;
        property = jo.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p =>
            string.Equals(p.Name, parts[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        );
    }

    if (property != null && property.Type != JTokenType.Null) {
        return property.Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

and the overridden `CanConvert` which will check of any properties have nested paths

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
     //Check if any JsonPropertyAttribute has a nested property name {name}.{sub}
    return objectType
        .GetProperties()
        .Any(p => 
            p.CanRead 
            && p.CanWrite
            && p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                .Any(jp => (jp.PropertyName ?? p.Name).Contains('.'))
        );
}
```

Comment: Also worked like a charm. You may see it working [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a6REyd).

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi note that with this example you can exclude the `JsonProperty` attributes as once they match the json naming they will be mapped automatically

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it works with less intervention than @Ivan one. I will wait until the bounty expiration for more answers if any. Thanks a lot, for now, kudos!

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution is to use custom JsonConverter but not implement all converting logic from scratch.

Some time ago I found and updated [JsonPathConverter](https://github.com/llatinov/DotNetSamples/blob/master/JsonPathConverter/JsonPathConverter.cs) which allows to use property path for JsonProperty attribute. For example in your case

```
 [JsonProperty("_embedded.company")]
 public LegalPerson Company { get; set; }
```

So your models with attributes will look like:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_embedded.company")]
    public LegalPerson Company { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
public class LegalPerson
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("industrySector")]
    public string IndustrySector { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("owner")]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_embedded.emailAddresses")]
    public ContactInfo[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_embedded.phoneNumbers")]
    public ContactInfo[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The code of JsonPathConverter is this. But I believe you can improve it.

```
  public class JsonPathConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var properties = value.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite);
        JObject main = new JObject();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            string jsonPath = att != null ? att.PropertyName : prop.Name;

            if (serializer.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver resolver)
                jsonPath = resolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(jsonPath);

            var nesting = jsonPath.Split('.');
            JObject lastLevel = main;

            for (int i = 0; i < nesting.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (i == (nesting.Length - 1))
                {
                    lastLevel[nesting[i]] = new JValue(prop.GetValue(value));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lastLevel[nesting[i]] == null)
                        lastLevel[nesting[i]] = new JObject();

                    lastLevel = (JObject) lastLevel[nesting[i]];
                }
            }
        }

        serializer.Serialize(writer, main);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jo = JToken.Load(reader);
        object targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objectType.GetRuntimeProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
        {
            var attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).ToArray();

            JsonIgnoreAttribute ignoreAttribute = attributes.OfType<JsonIgnoreAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (ignoreAttribute != null)
                continue;

            JsonPropertyAttribute att = attributes.OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            string jsonPath = att != null ? att.PropertyName : prop.Name;

            if (serializer.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver resolver)
                jsonPath = resolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(jsonPath);

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(jsonPath, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$"))
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"JProperties of JsonPathConverter can have only letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens and dots but name was ${jsonPath}."); // Array operations not permitted

            JToken token = jo.SelectToken(jsonPath);

            if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
            {
                object value;
                var jsonConverterAttr = attributes.OfType<JsonConverterAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (jsonConverterAttr == null)
                {
                    value = token.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer);
                }
                else
                {
                    var converter = (JsonConverter) Activator.CreateInstance(jsonConverterAttr.ConverterType,
                        jsonConverterAttr.ConverterParameters);

                    var r = token.CreateReader();
                    r.Read();
                    value = converter.ReadJson(r, prop.PropertyType, prop.GetValue(targetObj),
                        new JsonSerializer());
                }

                prop.SetValue(targetObj, value, null);
            }
        }

        return targetObj;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // CanConvert is not called when [JsonConverter] attribute is used
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally you can use it like this:

```
var json = "*your json string here*";
var customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json);
```

Comment: This worked as expected with very low intervention to models. Great! You can see working [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r1DPpy). I will try @Nkosi version now.

Comment: @Nkosi I reviewed the code of JsonPathConverter and realized that it could be implemented better. And [here](https://github.com/ichepikov/JsonNetExtension/blob/master/src/JsonNetExtension/Converters/NestedPropertyJsonConverter.cs) it is. According to my Benchmarks it works about 2 times faster and supports more Newtonsoft Json attributes like JsonIgnore and JsonConverter.

Comment: can I now run it without the `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]` decorator?

Comment: Ivan, you mean that you improved @Nkosi version? If so, that's great!

Comment: So true, I also did my own try and it's really way faster. Kudos @Ivan!

Answer (score 1):

The `company` object will be under `Embedded _embedded` object.

like

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"id\": \"4a17d6fe-a617-4cf8-a850-0fb6bc8576fd\",\"country\": \"DE\",\"_embedded\": {\"company\": {\"name\": \"Apple\",\"industrySector\": \"IT\",\"owner\": \"Klaus Kleber\",\"_embedded\": {\"emailAddresses\": [{\"id\": \"4a17d6fe-a617-4cf8-a850-0fb6bc8576fd\",\"value\": \"test2@consoto.com\",\"type\": \"Business\",\"_links\": {\"self\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"}}}],\"phoneNumbers\": [{\"id\": \"4a17d6fe-a617-4cf8-a850-0fb6bc8576fd\",\"value\": \"01670000000\",\"type\": \"Business\",\"_links\": {\"self\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"}}}],},\"_links\": {\"self\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"},\"phoneNumbers\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"},\"addresses\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"},}},},\"_links\": {\"self\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"},\"legalPerson\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"},\"naturalPerson\": {\"href\": \"https://any-host.com/api/v1/customers/1234\"}}}";

            CustomerJson results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerJson>(json);
            Customer customer = new Customer()
            {
                Id = results.id,
                Country = results.country,
                Company = new LegalPerson()
                {
                    EmailAddresses = results._embedded.company._embedded.emailAddresses,
                    PhoneNumbers = results._embedded.company._embedded.phoneNumbers,
                    IndustrySector = results._embedded.company.industrySector,
                    Name = results._embedded.company.name,
                    Owner = results._embedded.company.owner
                }
            };

        }

    }

    public class EmbeddedContactInfoJson
    {
        public ContactInfo[] emailAddresses { get; set; }
        public ContactInfo[] phoneNumbers { get; set; }
    }
    public class CompanyJson
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string industrySector { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public EmbeddedContactInfoJson _embedded { get; set; }
        public EmbeddedLinksJson _links { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmbeddedJson
    {
        public CompanyJson company { get; set; }
    }
    public class HrefJson
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmbeddedLinksJson
    {
        public HrefJson self { get; set; }
        public HrefJson phoneNumbers { get; set; }
        public HrefJson addresses { get; set; }
    }
    public class LinksJson
    {
        public HrefJson self { get; set; }
        public HrefJson legalPerson { get; set; }
        public HrefJson naturalPerson { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomerJson
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public EmbeddedJson _embedded { get; set; }
        public LinksJson _links { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public LegalPerson Company { get; set; }
    }
    public class LegalPerson
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IndustrySector { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public ContactInfo[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }
        public ContactInfo[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    }
    public class ContactInfo
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: No need to work out of the box, it can work with custom `JsonConverter` even. But I cannot change the models. That's a requirement.

Comment: Besides, will be an ugly solution to create a new `Embedded` type per model. Eg. `CompanyEmbbeded`, `LegalPersonEmbedded`, `OtherModelEmbedded` and on.

Comment: I understand the idea, I got your point. but there are 2 things: 1) I cannot change the models' structure, so I must restore the value to the currently existing models. 2) Having those `Self1`, `Self2`, `Embedded1`, `Embedded2` are really an ugly solution. I'm looking for something pinpoint. Eg: Creating a `[Embedded]` attribute and deal in a custom `JsonConverter`. I don't know yet how to solve it.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi I have updated code.1) JSON Parse with this model using `JsonConverter` after that map the result with your existing model. 2) I have changed the model names as `Self1`, `Self2`. You can also change the class name as you wish, it won't be an issue. Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: No `Embedded` class should be added because I cannot change the structure of the models.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi II have update code at first Parse JSON with this JSON moded to own Class then map to currently existing models